# Volume of the solid from rotation

Tags: calculus, functions, volume, curves

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the given curves about the specified axis.
$y=3x^2, x=1, y=0$, about the x-axis.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use Disk Method:

$$A(x)=\pi(\mbox{Outer radius})^2-\pi(\mbox{Inner radius})^2$$